# Allocating an array of structures within an array of structures

Tags: c, malloc

How can I allocate with **malloc** and array of structures within and array of structures?

for expample:

```
struct car_t{
int price;
float kmsDriven;
};

struct garage_t{
int locationX;
int locationY;
struct car_t * car;
}
```

There's an array of garages, which every one of them has an array of cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a loop:

```
#define N 42
#define M 17

struct garage_t *a = malloc(sizeof *a  * N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    a[i].car = malloc(sizeof (*a[i].car) * M);
}
```

Comment: `a` is `struct garage_t *` and `a[i]` is `struct garage_t`. So, Use `a[i].car` instead of `a[i]->car`.

Answer (score 1):

Just allocate as usual, one by one.

```
int garage_num = 3, car_num = 5;
int i;
struct garage_t *garage;
garage = malloc(sizeof(struct garage_t) * garage_num);
for (i = 0; i < garage_num; i++) {
    garage[i].car = malloc(sizeof(struct car_t) * car_num);
}
```

You should check if `malloc()`s are successful for actual use.